# Inserting textbox field into repeating field/line.text in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

![The Report has 3 groups - this show first ASSETS, employer contributions down is LineText repeating field, and to the right not in picture is current year and year to date totals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVimG.png)
I am building a report where I need to add a few textbox fields in-between the fields that have an account matched with them as this is a financial report that needs to match the Schedule Form (government form)that is non-specific and has accounts listed that this company does not.

I have tried inserting a section and suppressing the repeats of the textbox and this worked for a couple of items but some are in the middle of a section number.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the screen shot of your problem

Comment: I guess I could - but I have no idea how to post a screen shot as it won't paste in the comment area so I am guessing there is another way. Still, the picutre won't explin much other than I have the report grouped by ASSET/LIABLITY/OWNERS EQUITY and then in each section the account descriptions are displayed (line text) and to the right of each is the account balance both for Current Year & Previous Year. I need to add in between different accounts want I am mimicking which is a Schedule from the gov't that has lines that refer to accounts we do not have;I have an idea and will try it today.

Comment: attach a image by editing the question... and using image option

Comment: Nevermind - I have found a way where I have individually textboxed and hidden all other occurences (it was a repeating field) using an 'if...then' based off of the following field.----Now I need to close up the blank spots ie. the spots where I had to expand the sections for the textboxes but they only appear once so the rest of it appears blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, in a way. I have successfully inserted what needed to be there, but now have the resulting blank space must be deleted.

Comment: Try supress blank section option else you can also try to supress using the formula.... in supress part of the formula editor

Comment: Thank you Siva. Because I wrote a formula in the formatting for the text boxes that had them appear where I needed them but suppress otherwise I also checked the can grow option and in the design portion made the boxes shrinked down to a line and all on top of each other. It doesn't get rid of ever inch of spacing, but what is left I can deal with.>>Thank you so much for you assistance!